# Adb wifi connection with Android 6.0

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow, adbwireless

I have a Nexus 6 device with Android 6.0, stock version without root. To avoid to permanently connect device with usb cable i used this [procedure](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html):

1. I connected the device by USB cable to PC
2. type on terminal `adb tcpip 5555`.
3. type `adb connect <device-ip>:5555` to connect in wifi mode.

When i try to deploy an app from Android Studio, the connection is lost.

I used this procedure many times and with other devices (without Android 6) and i have no problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My device with Android 6.0.0, too, failed to connect, but after the official upgrade to 6.0.1, this problem was solved.

Comment: I second this. Wireless adb connection is completely broken in Android 6.0. Updating to 6.0.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: my s6 has 6.0.1 and as long as i leave the USB cable plugged in the "adb wifi" connection lasts, but as soon as i unplug it ( or it randomly dies ) i lose the connection and get the dreaded "actively refused" message when trying to reconnect...

Answer (score 3):

It works for my G-TiDE V7s (Android 6.0),

### I just discovered that I don't need usb cable, not even for the first time as many people think so.

Its just: (**do not use usb cable at all**)

`adb tcpip 5555`

### Then

`adb connect <device-ip>:5555`

Comment: you can't set `tcpip` if you have no devices connected at the moment

Comment: Work for me, you save my day! Thx

Comment: Work for me without usb cable. :)

Comment: It's working on Android 9.0, no need for a cable @all, please test it 1st before the judge, user25.

Comment: Confirmed Jan 2020 on Android 8.0.0. Much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows... (no need for cable at all! Root users)

Craigs auto wifi adb..

Auto connects to pc
Auto reconnects if wifi is dropped
The apk contains the windows client
No typing involved at all for rooted users, no scripts, run the app on android boxes/phones all at the same time!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=controller.adb.craigs.craigswifiadb

Comment: If, as seems likely, this is your software, you should be a bit more explicit about your link to it. Also, [make sure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) you're doing a lot more than simply hawking your products here, with the majority of your answers having little or nothing to do with them (or explaining to existing users how to program with your products, like an MS rep answering coding questions about VS or C#).

Comment: craig+s wifi adb worked on my tv box android 6.0.1 tks

Answer (score 0):

After you enter

```sh
adb connect <device-ip>:5555
```

you don't need to connect in Android Studio. It's already connected, just run the project and your phone will be in the list without using a cable.