# ADB error after installing latest SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk, adb

I have recently downloaded the latest SDK version which is api 26 and I am getting this error while trying to connect to my device over Wifi.

```
adb connect 123.456.78.90:5555
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
** daemon still not running
error: cannot connect to daemon: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

I have tried many other solutions such as killing adb.exe in task manager available in the other SO posts but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Follow the advice in this post: [Android Studio wireless ADB error 10061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267335/android-studio-wireless-adb-error-10061)

Comment: @Elletlar Thanks for the answer but even using this command `adb devices` gives me this error. The link tells to connect the device and the machine to the same network where as both of the for me are connected to same Wifi.

Comment: @Elletlar Thanks but updating to latest platform tools SDK version solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found out the issue. Updating the SDK Platform tool version also helped me to solve the issue.