# Can't connect through ADB to device's port

Tags: android, connection, adb, port, nmap

I'm trying to connect to a TV set-top box. After issuing "adb connect my_IP_address" I get this error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)". I've tried many basic solutions like the ones from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267335/android-studio-wireless-adb-error-10061) but they either don't work or I can't attempt them since they require a USB cable connection and my device dosen't respond to that for some reason.

USB debugging is enabled and I'm sure the device is connected to the same network since I successfully pinged it. Surprisingly I discovered that the 5555 port which is usually used for connecting isn't even open. I got that from using Nmap to check for a particular port. Then I used Nmap to see which ports are open and only got 3:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
```

8008/tcp open  http
8009/tcp open  ajp13
9000/tcp open  cslistener

None of those is suitable for a connection and it looks like there is no available port? What can I do from here?

Comment: you need to open the port 5555 first.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to open the 5555 port for communication

Step to open the port

1. plug your device to the pc
2. issue command to open the port ***adb start-server 5555***
3. ***adb connect my_IP_address:5555***

Comment: I can't plug my device to the PC, like I said it doesn't connect to the USB cable.