# How to connect ADB over wifi network without usb cable?

Tags: android, adb

I want to connect my adb to real-time android, not to emulator but it gives an error: "cannot connect to 192.168.10.4:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)"
I tried this command: adb connect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio wireless ADB error (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267335/android-studio-wireless-adb-error-10061)

Comment: Did you run this command `adb -s <device id> tcpip 5555` before adb connect?

Comment: **TL;DR:** Google actively and deliberately made this not possible. You will not find a solution below. **The only correct answer is to not buy any product over which you don’t have full control.** As such devices are crimes that are strangely still “legal”. Prevent such organized crime (Yes, organized crime. I has to be said.), and buy one of the many phones where the bootloader is not locked. E.g. a Fairpone.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible starting with Android 11. On the phone click *Pair device with pairing code*, then on the dev machine do the following:

```
cd myandroidsdk/platform-tools
adb pair ipaddr:port
```

Take `ipaddr` and `port` from your phone. The terminal will then prompt you to put in the pairing code.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+

Answer (score 6):

In latest updates of Android Studio, you can easily pair your device wirelessly

Go to  `Device Manager > Physical > Pair using Wi-Fi`

Then go to your phone's settings  `Developer options > Wireless debugging > Pair using QR code`
Your phone will be connected to Android Studio after scanning the QR code

```
Note: this feature works on Android 11+ devices
```

> Old Devices

**Make sure your phone and laptop are connected to the same router**

- connect your phone to your laptop with usb cable
- open a terminal window
- `adb devices`

  shell response should be something like this:

  `List of devices attached E1MGAP2810904770        device`
- `adb tcpip 5556`
- `adb connect 192.168.1.47:5556`

  shell response should be something like this:

  `connected to 192.168.1.47:5556`

change the 192.168.1.47 with your local IP address.

you can find your phone's IP Address in Settings -> Status ...

Comment: Yes, I tried the above commands. But the problem is that I want to connect my android to ADB without cable and also want to gain root access through terminal. I couldn't achieve this target. I made sure that my Laptop and Android are connected to the same wifi network.

Comment: first of all you have to use cable, then, after connecting throw wireless you can unplug your phone and work wireless

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link to get the detailed answer :

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

And one more think , don't connect your mobile with charger while connecting the android studio to mobile without usb cable.

Answer (score 0):

In android 11 device and above there is direct way to use wifi debugging. Make sure your computer and your android device are in same wifi network. Then  follow the steps -

```
    1. Open terminal in the directory of adb. So for windows Open cmd in ...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

    2. Run `adb devices` to confirm that no device is connected

    3. run `adb connect <IP address of your device>:5555` 

    4. Run `adb devices` again, it should show your physical device.
```

May be you have to install any app through usb debugging by connecting usb first. Then afterwards the above method works for that phone (My Android Studio version is Flamingo 2022.2.1).

In linux use `./adb` instead of `adb`. Go to the Settings -> About phone -> All Specs -> Status to view the IP address of your phone.

Answer (score -2):

Connect to DNS Server IPv4 address instead of just IPv4 address. Check in your wireless properties.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean?