# adb over Wi-Fi (Android 11+) on Windows: how to keep a fixed port or connect automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, adbwireless

The [wireless adb connection](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+) works fine on my Android 11 phone + Windows workstation.

But it's not convenient, as every time the phone Wifi disconnects/reconnects, I have to:

1. Turn on wireless debugging in Android settings.
2. Take note of the port number XXXXX, which changes every time!
3. Run `adb connect 192.168.1.10:XXXXX` on the computer.

Is there a way to skip step 2, by either:

- making the port fixed?
- making Windows automatically detect the phone on the new port? (documentation seems to imply that step 2 and 3 are not needed on MacOS, once the pairing is done, I wonder how this works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is now solved thanks to a recent update of Android Studio.

All steps can now be automated:

1. Turn on wireless debugging in Android settings.
   → this can be automated with a simple [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) profile: when connected to your office wifi, set a custom setting to enable wireless debugging like so:

[image: tasker profile]

[image: tasker task]

Or if you don't need full automation, you can probably add a quick switch for convenience. On a Pixel 3 it can be done in `Settings > System > Developer options > Quick settings developer tiles > Wireless debugging`

2. Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 now automatically (after a few seconds) detects the device and connects to it! 
   No more copying of port numbers.

Comment: Update after a few months: the detection of the device by Android Studio is, unfortunately, *extremely* unreliable and inconsistent.

Answer (score 21):

You can make the port fixed until reboot by `adb tcpip`

After pairing and connecting with the dynamic port

try `adb tcpip 5555`

then you can use
`adb connect ip:5555` until reboot (ya after reboot you've to connect with dynamic port and set tcpip to 5555 again)

Edit:
I run this command whenever i reboot my phone

```
adbw() {
    adb connect $IP:$1
    adb tcpip 5555
    adb disconnect
    adb connect $IP:5555
}
```

Comment: by reboot you mean the computer's or the phone's reboot?

Comment: phone's reboot...
I've edited the answer by adding my workflow

Comment: Instead of providing the current IP address of the phone, it is sufficient to use `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`). So you can simplify also your script, replacing `$IP`.

Comment: Even simpler, since `5555` is the default adb port and `::1` and `::` are shorthand IPv6 addresses of the current machine, `adb connect <ip address>:5555` can be simplified to `adb connect ::`

Answer (score 17):

You can dynamically get port using `nmap` and connect to it.

here is my solution

`adb connect <device_ip>:$(nmap $IP -p 37000-44000 | awk "/\/tcp/" | cut -d/ -f1)`

Scanning only ports 37000-44000 is sufficient
Also wireless debugging should be enabled and device needs to unlocked during nmap scan.
Run it again if the nmap doesn't find the port first time.

I have added the command to an alias so it is easy to run
ex:
`alias adbw='adb connect 192.168.0.7:$(nmap $IP -p 37000-44000 | awk "/\/tcp/" | cut -d/ -f1)'`

To connect next time:

1. Unlock Device
2. Enable Wireless debugging (you can add it to status bar icons)
3. run `adbw` if alias set.

Ex Output:
`connected to 192.168.0.7:38395`

Comment: As my phone has several ports open in this range, the following worked fine for me: adbw='for p in \`nmap 192.168.0.7 -p 37000-44000 | awk "/\/tcp/" | cut -d/ -f1\`; do adb connect 192.168.0.7:$p ; done'

Answer (score 9):

Android broadcasts the connection details over mDNS/DNS-SD with a service type of `._adb-tls-connect._tcp`.

You can discover Android devices with wireless adb enabled using something like avahi-browse.

```bash
$ avahi-browse --terminate --resolve _adb-tls-connect._tcp
+    br0 IPv6 adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf                           _adb-tls-connect._tcp local
+    br0 IPv4 adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf                           _adb-tls-connect._tcp local
+ enp5s0 IPv6 adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf                           _adb-tls-connect._tcp local
=    br0 IPv6 adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf                           _adb-tls-connect._tcp local
   hostname = [Android.local]
   address = [10.0.0.199]
   port = [37531]
   txt = ["v=ADB_SECURE_SERVICE_VERSION"]
=    br0 IPv4 adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf                           _adb-tls-connect._tcp local
   hostname = [Android.local]
   address = [10.0.0.199]
   port = [37531]
   txt = ["v=ADB_SECURE_SERVICE_VERSION"]
= enp5s0 IPv6 adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf                           _adb-tls-connect._tcp local
   hostname = [Android.local]
   address = [10.0.0.199]
   port = [37531]
   txt = ["v=ADB_SECURE_SERVICE_VERSION"]
```

Then you can connect using the service name.

```bash
$ adb connect adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf
connected to adb-26df62cd-sGvUmf._adb-tls-connect._tcp
```

Or using the address and port.

```bash
$ adb connect 10.0.0.199:37531
connected to 10.0.0.199:37531
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I've created a shell script based on your information https://gist.github.com/gnumoksha/f9a5b2e01b1e74ffa2a055b6e18f7c58

Comment: This is indeed a **very** underrated answer, using such technique you can write a script to automatically connect to your phone when it appears. The ID also seems to look like persistent, so you can use that to filter to which phones to connect.

Comment: Thanks, it works well on Ubuntu. it could be the answer for this question if we have 'avahi-browse' or alternatives for Windows OS.

Answer (score 4):

I liked Build3r's answer so i ported it to powershell, you only need to install nmap which is available for windows:

`nmap YOUR_IP -p 37000-44000 | Where-Object{$_ -match "tcp open"} | ForEach-Object {$_.split("/")[0]}`

i use this in a python script which is in my PATH

```py
ret=subprocess.run(["powershell","-command",F'nmap {ip} -p 37000-44000 | Where-Object{{$_ -match "tcp open"}} | ForEach-Object {{$_.split("/")[0]}}'],capture_output=True)
port=ret.stdout.decode().strip()
```

Comment: for anyone else wondering like I was, you can directly put in the following in powershell after having installed nmap to complete adb connection: `adb connect YOUR_IP:$(nmap YOUR_IP -p 37000-44000 | Where-Object{$_ -match "tcp open"} | ForEach-Object {$_.split("/")[0]})`

Comment: The port range should be wider than 37000-44000. My current device uses port 34869.

Comment: I used this extensively on my phone with android 11. can you share your android version or phone model?

Comment: On my Nokia G42 it works well, the problem is that with my Samsung M34 the nmap scan takes like 15 minutes until it finds the port, so it's very inconvenient.

Answer (score 3):

Building back on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878705) from [Build3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3125800/build3r), here is the PowerShell snippet in order to get a one-line solution for wireless `adb` on Windows :

```
adb connect $IP`:$(((nmap $IP -p 37000-44000 | sls tcp) -Split '/')[0])
```

---

You'll need to define your device IP (a DHCP permanent lease would come in handy there) beforehand via :

```
$IP="192.168.0.69"
```

Some documentation regarding the required `adb` pairing before being able to use this snippet : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless-android11-command-line

Answer (score 2):

Building back on the answer from Build3r and SonicGold.I write a bat script with Python to auto connect.
Python:

```
ip = "192.168.10.136"
ret = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-command",
                      F"((nmap {ip} -p 37000-44000 | sls tcp) -Split '/')"],
                     capture_output=True)
outputs = ret.stdout.decode().strip().split("\n")
for output in outputs:
    output = output.replace("\r", "")
    if output.isalnum():
        print(f"find port:{output}")
        print(subprocess.run(["powershell", "-command",
                              F"adb connect {ip}:{output}"],
                             capture_output=True).stdout.decode().strip()
              )
time.sleep(5)
```

bat:

```
"python" "xxx\scanWifi.py"
```

It can scan all the match port and try to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found below ways for both Linux and Windows (hope it will help for others). Because ADB 31.0.2 or later disables mDNS discovery, you must enable mDNS discovery and then restart the ADB server.

Linux:

```
export ADB_MDNS_OPENSCREEN=1
adb kill-server
adb start-server 
adb mdns services
```

Windows:

```
set ADB_MDNS_OPENSCREEN=1
adb kill-server
adb start-server 
adb mdns services
```

Outputs (for example):

```
List of discovered mdns services
driver_vm       _adb._tcp       192.168.1.49:4444
device_vm       _adb._tcp       192.168.1.49:3333
```

if there is only one devices, it automatically connects to the devices every time wireless debugging is enabled on this device. Otherwise you can use `connect` command as shown below

```
adb connect driver_vm._adb._tcp
```

or

```
adb connect 192.168.1.49:3333
```

Reference: https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/virtualization/tools

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that once you have paired the device, you will never be asked for anything again to connect to that device (except you later revoke the permissions manually).

To pair a device from adb, first you have to asure the following in this checklist:

1. You are on the same net (e.g.: your laptop and oyur phone)
2. You have activated **Wireless debug** on your phone

Once you have confirmmed those things, you have to go to developers menu in your phone (the one where you can find wireless debug option). Enter in that submenu and go to the option "pair with code". A popup with certain data will be shown. With that in sight, you go to the terminal and put this command:

```
abd pair <your-device-ip>:<device-port> <pairing-code>
```

With that already done, you always will see that device in the list of devices when you do an **adb devices** in your laptop (if all the points from checklist are accomplished)

Comment: This solution is not working for me. After pairing, upon connection request I get `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)` The port keep changing like before I can only connect using currently used port number. Don't see the point of pairing...

Comment: mmm...It sounds to me like there is a network issue around there...You can check this post about that: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267335/android-studio-wireless-adb-error-10061).
I get so much help from adb official doc. You can check here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267335/android-studio-wireless-adb-error-10061)

Answer (score 0):

A hint on all the solutions discussed here and on using `adb sync` and `adb connect` for wireless debugging with ADB in general:

Instead of providing the (awkward, possibly even volatile) current IP address of the mobile device, it is sufficient to use `localhost` (or the equivalent IPv4 address `127.0.0.1` or IPv6 address `::1`).