# Make Python Subprocess Run in PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I'm trying to [get the wireless debugging port of ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878705) in my Android, using [the command here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653477):

`& "D:\Tools\Nmap\nmap.exe" -T4 192.168.2.20 -p 37000-44000 | Where-Object {$_ -match "tcp open"} | ForEach-Object {$_.split("/")[0]}`

And I would like to make a Python script for further purposes:

```py
ip = '192.168.2.20'
nmap_path = r'D:\Tools\Nmap\nmap.exe'


def get_port():
    port_result = subprocess.run(
        f'& "{nmap_path}" -T4 {ip} -p 37000-44000 | '
        f'Where-Object {{$_ -match "tcp open"}} | '
        f'ForEach-Object {{$_.split("/")[0]}}',
        shell=True
    )
    port = port_result.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()
    return port
```

But it gave the following error: `& was unexpected at this time.`, which indicated that the command was run in CMD instead of PowerShell.

[image: cmd vs ps]

I do not want to use `powershell -Command`, nor saving the commands into a `.ps1` file.

Could I make `subprocess.run` to run specifically in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) says `subprocess()` uses `COMSPEC` to determine which shell to run if you set `shell=True`.

I don't have, want, or use Windows, but imagine you'd need something like:

```
import os
import subprocess

# Change COMSPEC to point to Powershell
os.putenv('COMSPEC',r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe')

subprocess.run(..., shell=True)
```

I'm assuming you can check that path.

---

I guess it would probably be good practice to save and restore the previous COMSPEC in case the change to Powershell upsets something else. So:

```
# Save original COMSPEC
savedCOMSPEC = os.getenv('COMSPEC')

... CODE FROM ABOVE ...

# Restore previous COMSPEC
os.putenv('COMSPEC', savedCOMSPEC)
```

Comment: `os.putenv(k, v)` does not work on Windows (at least here), `os.environ[k] = v` does.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the path to powershell with the executable option of run.

```
powershell_path = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe'
subprocess.run(
    'echo This is simpler', 
    shell=True,
    executable=powershell_path,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

test it yourself, it's not compatible sometimes

```
import subprocess 
cmds = '''adb shell "ls /data/local && pwd"
adb shell ls /data/local && pwd
adb shell ls /data/local && adb shell pwd
$(adb shell ls /data/local && pwd)
$(adb shell ls /data/local) && pwd
'''
capture_output=False

powershell='C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe'
for cmd in cmds.splitlines():
    cmd = f'"{powershell}" -command {cmd}'
    print('@'*5+cmd)
    r=subprocess.run(cmd,capture_output=capture_output)
    print(r.returncode)

print('-'*20)
powershell = 'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe'
for cmd in cmds.splitlines():
    cmd = f'{powershell} -command {cmd}'
    print('@'*5+cmd)
    r=subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=capture_output)
    print(r.returncode)

print('-'*20)
powershell = 'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe'
for cmd in cmds.splitlines():
    print('@'*5+cmd)
    r=subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True,executable=powershell, capture_output=capture_output)
    print(r.returncode)

print('-'*20)
for cmd in cmds.splitlines():
    print('@'*5+cmd)
    r=subprocess.run(cmd,capture_output=capture_output)
    print(r.returncode)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You could go about this by **pip-installing nmap** in powershell by running powershell as administrator and running:

```
pip install nmap
pip install python-nmap
```

Then, head back to your python script, call powershell using **subprocess.call** followed by your path to **powershell.exe**, then the desired command to execute:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

subprocess.call(f'C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe nmap -T4 -p 37000-44000', shell=True)
```

OR

**Option 2:**

You could just **import nmap as a package** into your python script, still making sure that you **pip-installed nmap AND python-nmap.**

```
import nmap
scan = nmap.PortScanner()

scan.scan({ip}, '37000-44000')
```

I found a [detailed article](https://www.studytonight.com/network-programming-in-python/integrating-port-scanner-with-nmap) explaining how to do the **latter method**. (Importing nmap directly into your script as a package, that is.)

Best of luck and happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, `os.environ` must be used to set '`COMSPEC`' instead of `os.putenv`

```
from subprocess import run
import os

# Change COMSPEC to point to Powershell
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env['COMSPEC'] = r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'

#run process
args = [<arguments>]
p = run(args, shell=True, env = my_env)
```