# how to use avahi to get adb wifi port

Tags: android

I want use termux to get adb wifi port
but termux can not instal avahi-daemon or dbus
so,I proot-distro install ubuntu
It can finally be downloaded successfully

but here is something wrong with dbus:

root@localhost:~# service dbus start

- Starting system message bus dbus                            [ OK ]
  root@localhost:~# service dbus status
- dbus is not running

It tuns successfully on the windows system Linux
but it can not scan Phone

I want to get adb wifi port
If I get it, then I can do the following:
termux:
adb connect 127.0.0.1:ip
adb tcpip 5555

It can be activated adb wifi every time the phone is turned on

[adb over Wi-Fi (Android 11+) on Windows: how to keep a fixed port or connect automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991502/adb-over-wi-fi-android-11-on-windows-how-to-keep-a-fixed-port-or-connect-aut)