# Android force idle mode vs. really unplug the device

Tags: android, debugging, battery, screen-off

Currently I'm working on an app which does Bluetooth scanning in background service. 
I realized that the phones behaviour is different if I force the device to sleep mode by

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

or unplug the physical cable from the device.

I can't find information about that there is a difference. But I recognised a difference already on different devices.

Is there a way to put the device in a I-physical-unplug-and-put-screen-off-mode and still be able to debug with logcat?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You may find it useful to `adb connect` over Wi-Fi to your device, as indeed Doze mode may behave differently when the phone is being charged. You can then run the `force-idle` command with the device unplugged. Instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36080928/1123355